# Proper print using fprintf in matlab

Tags: matlab, printf

So I have the function print_date which goes

`fprintf('%d.%d.%d\n, date.day, date.month, date.year)`

Which in this case prints out "20.5.1990"

But I want to remove the \n part because Im need to use this function in another. However, when I remove the \n, the output on the print_date becomes, I dont know how to explain. But the
the ">>" at the beginning of the command window becomes:
"20.5.1990>>" instead of "20.5.1990"

How do I fix this?

Comment: You "fix" this behaviour inserting a new line `\n` at the end. If you print `20.5.1990` and matlab returns to the console, a `>>` is printed to indicate that matlab is waiting for the next input. Maybe inserting a `fprintf('\n')` once at the end of your code might solve it for you.

Comment: Note: `date` is an inbuilt matlab function, so you should try to avoid using it as a variable name.  Also, you might want to look into `datestr` and related functions.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the function `print_date` in another function, add a return value to `print_date`. The `fprintf` writes data to text file or to the console window. If the output string needs to be stored into a variable, use `sprintf`. You can then display the value of the variable using `disp`. Here's an example, but I recommend you to read the documentation for more info.

```
function s=print_date(date)

s=sprintf('%d.%d.%d', date.day, date.month, date.year);
disp(s);

end
```